# LINK : fatal error LNK1212: error opening program database; file is in use

Tags: vb6

LINK : fatal error LNK1212: error opening program database; file is in use

While creating .exe from my VB project, getting the above error.
The .exe could not be built successfully.

Comment: Did you try again and get the same error?  My antivirus occasionally causes an error like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the .exe or some other output file (e.g. .pdb file) is read-only

Comment: +1 Probably the PDB file from the error message. Delete the PDB file and try again.